# I am trying to vectorize the scalar function

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, scalar

Here the code I had written

```
def scalar_function(x, y):
    """
    Returns the f(x,y) defined in the problem statement.
    """
    if x<=y:
       return (np.dot(x,y))
    else:
       return(x/y)

def vector_function(x, y):
    """
    Make sure vector_function can deal with vector input x,y 
    """
    vfunc = np.vectorize(scalar_function(x,y))
    return vfunc
```

Here is am trying to do as::scalar_function can only handle scalar input, we could use the function np.vectorize() turn it into a vectorized function. Note that the input argument of np.vectorize() should be a scalar function, and the output of np.vectorize() is a new function that can handle vector input.

But after running it I got an error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'vectorize'
```

Now I don't know what to do

```
NumPy as np
```

has imported already
Thank you

Comment: Have you read and understood the examples in the `np.vectorize` docs?  You aren't following that usage.

Comment: Also, `dot` seems a bit out of place for a scalar function. Unless you plan on treating columns or rows of a matrix as "scalars"?

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Comment: Please post an MCVE. How are you calling this? What result do you expect? What's up with `dot`?

Comment: The (first) argument to `np.vectorize` is supposed to be a function, not the result of running the function on some arguments.  `np.vectorize(func)` not `np.vectorize(func(x,y))`.

Comment: I agree with ALL comments above. While I gave an "answer", I'm not sure it answers the question. It would seem like you want a `dot` function, given you use np.dot, but my answer certainly is not that. My answer applies strictly to the question as stated: how to vectorize a scalar function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an extra arguement for vector_function as follows :

```
def vector_function(x, y , func):
    
    vfunc = np.vectorize(func)   
    return vfunc(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
def vector_function(x, y):
    """
    Make sure vector_function can deal with vector input x,y 
    """
    vector_function = np.vectorize(scalar_function)
    return vector_function(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it:

```
vector_function = np.vectorize(scalar_function)
```

Now my question is why would you do that. I bet things would run faster if you use a numpy function instead of vectorizing this.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to pass arguments into vfunc in return

```
def vector_function(x, y , func):
    
    vfunc = np.vectorize(func)   
    return vfunc(x,y)
```